# Implementation of cantor set without recursion

Tags: recursion

I'm working on the implementation of a cantor set on a 2-dimensional plane. It looks like this. Honestly, There is the obvious algorithm for the cantor set, but it includes a recursive method call. Unfortunately, My environment(Houdini vex) does not support recursive function calls, so I have to design the algorithm without using recursion.

1. Is it possible to represent a cantor set without recursion?
2. How can I represent the recursive thing in the algorithm without recursion?

[image: Cantor set implementation on a 2-dimensional grid]

```
int size=ch("size"); //size=27
int can[]={0};
int offset=0;
int col=size;
append(can,size);
int index=0;
int step=1;
int temp[]={};
int firstentry=0;

function void line(int x1; int x2)
{
    //this function gets x1(startpoint), x2(endpoint) and color entries in
        int step= x2-x1;
        if (step==0)
        {
            
        
        //color the single sqaure   
            setprimgroup(0,"cantor",x1,1,"set");
        }

        else{

             //setprimgroup do the role of coloring the squre.
       
            for(int i=x1; i<=step+x1; i++)
            {
                setprimgroup(0,"cantor",i,1,"set");
            }
        }
    
}
while(size>=1)
{
    //first step 0~26
    if(index<size)
    {
        //first line is set.
        setprimgroup(0,"cantor",index,1,"set");
        index+=1;
        
        //first entry indicates the first entry of the row.
        
    }
    
///
    else{
        //split by 1/3
        //first entry indicates the first entry of the row.
        firstentry+=col;
        size=size/3;
        step=step*2;

        //done only for subdivision ex 1,2,4...
        for(int i=0; i<step; i++)
        {
            
            offset = size*2;
            int start=index;
            int end= start+size-1;

          
            line(start,end);
            
            
            printf("start %g end %g \n",start,end);
            
            index+=offset;
           //
        }

        
        index=firstentry+col;
        

        //for recursive step, multiply by 2.
        
        
    }

    
}
```

this language resembles C, I don't want you to do coding for me. Please present just an idea for correcting the gap calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It can be expressed without recursion, as long as you have loops and data structures.  Any recursive algorithm can be converted to a non-recursive iterative algorithm, by introducing an explicit stack.  See, e.g., [Iteration can replace Recursion?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/67897/755), [Iterative and/or tail-recursive implementations of merge sort?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/13139/755), [Do we need recursion in programming language to solve any problem?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/41404/755).